# AWS redeploy a docker after update

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have an aws ec2 cluster with a service that runs a task. Let's say the task's image is `my-app:latest`

When I want to update the application I build a new docker image and push it to the ECR.

Now, how do I roll the new `my-app:latest` image to my instances?

Comment: Betzalel you can also do this using AWS console, let me know if you are looking for that so i can update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the Docker image involves two approaches

First one, only update docker image and push to ECR without modifying the tag that is`aws.abc/myimage:latest`, so, in this case, you do not need to update the task definition you just need to redeploy the service. you can do from AWS console or from aws cli

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster ec2cluster_name --service service_name --force-new-deployment
```

This all you need,

The second one, if you use different docker image tag then you also need to update task definition that will point to the new Docker image and redeploy the service.

Register new version of the task definition

Now specify the task definition revision. rest of the thing will be the same except the docker image tag.

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
  {
    "cpu": 0,
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "/ecs/stage-app",
        "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
  }
},
    "environment": [
      {
        "name": "BRANCH",
         "value":"staging"
      },
      {
        "name": "NODE_ENV",
        "value": "staging"
      }
    ],


    "memoryReservation": 400,

  "ulimits": [
    {
        "name": "nofile",
        "softLimit": 4000,
        "hardLimit": 4000
    }
],
    "image": "***.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stage:stage",
    "dockerLabels": {
      "Name": "stage-app"
    },
    "privileged": true,
    "name": "stage-app"
  }
],

"family": "stage-app"
}
```

Register this revision

`aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://stage-nodejs.json`

update the service with the new task definition

```
 aws ecs update-service --cluster cluster_name --service service_name --task-definition task_definition_name
```

redeploy the service

`aws ecs update-service --cluster ec2cluster_name --service service_name --force-new-deployment`